# How to invert a linear operator with constant coefficients?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given a linear operator $O[f] = c_0 f + c_1 f' + c_2 f'' + c_3 f''' ... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n f^{(n)} $, where all the $c_i$ are constant is it possible to find a nice closed form for the inverse of this operator, that is an operator $O^{-1}$ such that $O[O^{-1}] = f$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is possible, for at least a subset of all such operators.

To do so we begin by considering the function $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n$. We then look at the function $\frac{1}{g(z)} $ which we expand as $\frac{1}{g(z)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n z^n $. If such an inverse exists then the operator $H = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n f^{(n)}$ actually is the inverse of our original operator $O = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n f^{(n)}$. I.E. $O[H] = f, H[O] = f$.

We can compute some examples such as the following

$$ O[f] = f(x+1) = \frac{1}{0!} f + \frac{1}{1!} f' + \frac{1}{2!} f''+ ... $$

$$ O^{-1}[f] = f(x-1)  = \frac{1}{0!} f - \frac{1}{1!} f' + \frac{1}{2!} f'' - ... $$

Observe that $g(z) = e^z$ in this case and $\frac{1}{g(z)} = e^{-z}$. So that's where the coefficient of $O^{-1}$ come from.

We do another example, consider

$$O[f] = f - f'$$

By the geometric series formula one can see that it's claimed $$O^{-1}[f] = f + f' + f'' + f''' + ... $$

Now observe that $$ (f - f') + (f - f')' + (f- f')'' + ... = f + (-f' + f') + (-f'' + f'') + (-f''' + f''') + ... = f$$

Similarly one compose the other way and see that $$f + f' + f'' + f''' + ... - f' - f'' - f''' - ... = f + (f' - f') + (f'' - f'') + (f''' - f''') + ... = f $$

So there are at least two examples that work.

Now the proof of this principle is a bit more involved but basically what we have is that the linear map $L: z^n \rightarrow f^{(n)}$ induces a homomorphism between multiplication on its left hand side and operator composition on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

The operator is if the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nT^n$ where $Tf=f'.$ It is not surprising that the formal inverse operator is of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty d_nT^n$ for coefficients $d_n$ satisfying $$c_0d_0=1,\qquad \sum_{k=0}^nc_kd_{n-k}= 0,\ n\ge 1$$ The system is solvable exactly when $c_0\neq 0.$
The system of equations corresponds to the identity $$\sum c_nz^n \ \sum d_nz^n=1$$
Still there is possibility to invert operator of the form $$\sum_{n=m}^\infty c_nT^n=T^m\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n+m}T^n \ c_m\neq 0$$
by inverting $T^m$ and multiplying by the inverse of the sum. In the case of $Tf=f'$ we can use the antiderivatives $(T^{-1}f)(x)=\int\limits_0^xf(t)\,dt.$